# In Flutter, is it possible to use Provider to create a listener function

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

So I have this provider

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gotaxi_flutter/enums.dart';
import 'package:gotaxi_flutter/models/google_places_models/google_places_models.dart';

class PlaceInfo {
  GooglePlace place;
  bool isDestination;
  PlaceInfo(this.place, this.isDestination);
}

class RideInfoProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  CurrentRideScreen _currentRideScreen = CurrentRideScreen.none;
  PlaceInfo? _place;

  PlaceInfo? get place => _place;

  CurrentRideScreen get currentRideScreen => _currentRideScreen;

  void setCurrentRideScreen(CurrentRideScreen screen) {
    _currentRideScreen = screen;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  //set origin or destination locations
  void setPlace(GooglePlace place, bool isDestination) {
    _place = PlaceInfo(place, isDestination);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

How can I create something similar to the following inside my widget:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _rideInfoProvider = RideInfoProvider();

    _rideInfoProvider.addListener(() {
      print("RideInfoProvider changed");
      if (_rideInfoProvider.place != null) {
        print(_rideInfoProvider.place);
        //run other functions or instances that exist in this widget and may utilize the place variable
      }
    });

}
```

Because otherwise, I have to move the whole listener logic and variables to the provider.

Comment: Why can't you use the normal way of using a provider via a `consumer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add and remove your listener based on the stateful widget lifecycle.
This means that `myListenerFunction` will be called on each call to `notifyListeners()` from `RideInfoProvider` until the widget gets disposed.
Do add the listener as a separate function in order to be able to remove it later passing the same reference (to the function).

And as @josip-domazet commented I would not recommend using a consumer for this as that would call the `myListenerFunction` from inside the build method of a widget, so it would be called each time flutter repaints that widget, instead of only when a new change is made in the notifier.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _rideInfoProvider = context.read<RideInfoProvider>();

    _rideInfoProvider.addListener(myListenerFunction);

}


@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    _rideInfoProvider.removeListener(myListenerFunction);

}
```